# How to get number of keys in a bucket in bolt

Tags: database, go, bolt

I am using bolt to store data, in a bucket I store key as versioning and I only want to keep a maximum number of versions in a bucket. Then I want to know if in a bucket there are too many keys. However, I cannot find a simple way than traverse all keys and count.

Does anyone know how to get the number of keys in a bucket?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I've never heard of or used bolt, but [the docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/boltdb/bolt) suggest that the [`Stats`](https://godoc.org/github.com/boltdb/bolt#Bucket.Stats) method will do what you want.

Comment: Stats provides details about B-tree representation. It counts recursively and use it to balance the tree

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just walk over the bucket with `ForEach`.
You might need to filter the records - and you can do it following this way.